# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.(provider:TCP Provider,error:35)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, kubernetes

I have a backgroundservice built in .Net Core that executes a SQL Server database procedure as follows:

```
public int ExecuteProcedure(string connectionString, string sql, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
{
        var response = -99;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            // Create a SqlCommand, and identify it as a stored procedure.
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if(parameters != null)
                    SetParameters(sqlCommand, parameters);
                response = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        return response;
}
```

When I run the bakcgroundservice **on my local machine it runs without problems but when I use docker and kubernetes** I get the following error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
> Provider, **error: 35** - An internal exception was caught)

I have consulted in several places but all the answers I find are about restarting Visual Studio or IIS which does not apply in my case due to having the application in kubernetes

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the full and complete Exception including stack trace as text? I suspect that it's dying in System.Net.Security.SslStream while trying to setup an SSL/TLS encrypted connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is presented **by the image** used when building the docker container.

I was using the image: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim` but when I changed it to: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-bionic` worked fine.

From what I have been consulting it seems that the image that was failing me has a version of the TLS that is not compatible to make the successful connection with SqlServer